# Is the cokernel $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I have  matrix (in SageMath notation):

```
[-1  0  0  0 -1  0  1  0  0]
[ 0 -1  0  0  0 -1  0  1  0]
[ 0  0 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  1]
```

I have calculated its Smith normal form as follows:

```
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]  
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] 
[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

So is the cokernel $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}^3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix in question (call it $A$) fits in the exact sequence:

$$
\mathbb{Z}^9 \overset{A}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{Z}^3 \to \text{coker}(A).
$$

Here the cokernel is $\mathbb{Z}^3 / \text{Im}(A)$, but we know that $A$ is surjective (because it has full rank). So the cokernel is actually $0$.

In general, if your smith normal form has entries $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ on the leftmost diagonal (where the $a_k$ are allowed to be $0$), then the cokernel is exactly

$$\bigoplus_k \mathbb{Z} / a_k \mathbb{Z}$$

where $\mathbb{Z} / 1 \mathbb{Z} = 0$ and $\mathbb{Z} / 0\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$. This is part of what makes the SNF useful! It allows us to quickly read off the decomposition guaranteed by the [fundamental theorem of PID modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/0\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$?, So this means that if my matrix had six rows full of 0's the cokernel would be the direct sum of 6 $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Exactly! If your matrix has $6$ rows, all $0$s, then the cokernel would be $\mathbb{Z}^6$. If it had $6$ rows, where the first row was $(3,0,\ldots,0)$ and the other $5$ rows were all $0$s, then the cokernel would be $\mathbb{Z}/3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}^5$. Lastly, if the first row is $(5,0,\ldots,0)$ and the second row is $(0,10,\ldots,0)$ and the others are all $0$, then the cokernel would be $\mathbb{Z}/5 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/10 \oplus \mathbb{Z}^4$. And this pattern continues.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. If I interpret your question correctly you are looking at a group homomorphism $\varphi\colon\mathbb Z^9\to\mathbb Z^3$ given by the matrix

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

with Smith normal form

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Recall that $\operatorname{coker}\varphi=\mathbb Z^3/\operatorname{im}\varphi$ and the normal form tells us that $\varphi$ is surjective. Hence $\operatorname{coker}\varphi$ is trivial.